# How to get a value from a database using AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

.js

```
function displayPic(str){
    if(str=""){
        document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML="<img src='' class='slider'/>";
    }

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
            document.getElementByTagName("src").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

.php

```
    <form onclick="displayPic(this.value)" method="GET" action="gallery.php">
    <?php
    include 'konekcija.php';
    $upit = "SELECT * FROM slike";
    $rezultat = mysql_query($upit) or die(mysql_error());

    while($red = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)){
        echo "<div class='art_gallery'><img src='";
        echo $red['path'];
        echo "' class='gall' name='id_s' value='".$red['id']."' />".$red['id']."</div>";
    }
?>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['id_s'])){
            $q = $_GET['id_s'];
            echo $q;
            $upit2 = "SELECT path FROM slike where id=".$q;
            mysql_query($upit2) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<div id='slider' align='center'><img src='' class='slider'/></div>";}?>
</form>
```

Okay, here's what I'm trying to accomplish here.
Firstly, through PHP, I would load a whole gallery with paths taken from the database and all beind displayed in a line which is stylized with CSS.
Now I also added `IDs` of these pictures (paths to be precise) from the database as values.  What I wanted to do was when someone would click on one of the pics, I'd register the click using an `onclick` in HTML and calling a `JavaScript` function which contains `AJAX` code and finally displaying the full sized picture bellow.
Now I know I have errors in this code, logical ones, which I'm willing to fix, but one I can't get over is that for some reason, using `$_GET['id_s']` returns nothing.
I even tried, as seen in the code, to pass the `ID` values in these `DIVs` that contain all the pictures and then get that value with the `$_GET` method, but again, it yielded no results.

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: First PHP part goes through and the gallery thumbnails are displayed. They're displayed as thumbnails using CSS. But the problem is in $_GET['id_s'], it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You have ... many problems.

The first of which i believe is assigning `str` to null at the top of your `displayPic(str)` function. In javascript, `=` is assignment, and `==` tests equality (and `===` tests type as well).

So you're calling your `xmlhttp.open("GET", "", true);`, which is just going to call the current page again and return the page html again in the `responseText`.

Also, there is no `getElementByTagName(tag)` ...  `getElementsByTagName(tag)` on the other hand, will fetch you a list of nodes with that tag name...  I've never heard of a `src` tag in html.  perhaps you meant an `img` tag that you wanted to set the `src` of?

It also appears that you are using the same page to be the user's view of your webpage as well as your ajax endpoint.  This will probably not end well for you, but if you must, put in a test around the entire page so it doesn't spit back your entire webpage with all the images in it again as your `responseText`.  Something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['id_s']) { do my ajax thing } else { the normal webpage }
```

And your `onclick` needs to move to the images that have values themselves.  If you use `displayPic(this.value)` on the form, `this` will be the form, which has no value. The only elements you've set values on are the images, so that's where the `displayPic()` calls need to go.

Also, an img tag is not an input object...  in the javascript node object, it has no 'value' member.  you can get the 'value' attribute with:

```
displayPic(this.getAttribute('value'));
```

Or perhaps it would be easier to merely set that value to the img tag's id, and use this.id

and then, since it's merely a value you're passing in, you'll need to edit the string to be:

```
str = "?id_s=" + str;
```

so your query string on the get is changed with the id_s argument in it.

Comment: That sure made me feel like an idiot. But still, the problem remains, clicking on the image does not send its value to the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

ok, if i have understood the problem right, you are having an issue in accessing the pics in javascript, so what you need to do is change this portion

```
  while($red = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)){
        echo "<div class='art_gallery'><img src='";
        echo $red['path'];
        echo "' class='gall' name='id_s' value='".$red['id']."' />".$red['id']."</div>";
    }
```

to this :

```
 while($red = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)){
        echo "<div class='art_gallery'><img src='";
        echo $red['path'];
        echo "' class='gall' name='id_s' onclick='zoompic(".$red['id'].");' />".$red['id']."</div>";
    }
```

and now just access the function zoompic in javascript, and you have the id of clicked picture as argument, so you can do whatever you want with it.